# Performance Recommendation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, database-performance, database-partitioning

Have a table with 2 billion rows and having date column on non unique clustered index. the data can be updated for existing date records on every ETL run,  however, the update will not happen more than  beyond 2 years past from now. Also, we will keep adding new records for newer dates.  So, it hits performance on update and insert and even on read. Any recommendation to partition/archive in right way?

Comment: I suggest you add a tag for the dbms uses, since this seems to be a product specific question.

Comment: Sorry for that, It's Microsoft SQL Server 2016